# Two UPDATE queries at very same time

Tags: sql, database, transactions

Lets say we have a database with a table called `table` containing a row: `(id, column) = (0, 'zero')` and at *very same time* two clients performs their queries:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET column = 'one' 
WHERE id = 0 AND column = 'zero'
```

and

```sql
UPDATE table
SET column = 'two'   
WHERE id = 0 AND column = 'zero'
```

Is it possible that both clients will receive “1 row has been updated” from the database? 
Or, only one (random) client will *always* receive “1 row has been updated” while the other will *always* receive “0 rows has been updated”?

Comment: It is perhaps possible, but not if the database is properly configured to support the ACID properties of databases.  Relational databases implement ACID properties, but can often be configured to weaken them.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (locking vs optimistic.)

Comment: “1 row has been updated” comes at UPDATE. Who COMMITs first?

Comment: It depends on which isolation level was used.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the very same time" one of them is bound to be earlier than the other - it might be just by a nanosecond. The second one will then wait until the first one commits or rolls back. But the second one will then not see the row any longer and thus won't update anything

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why do you think that there is no such thing as “at the very same time”? Client queries can be handled by different CPU cores.

Comment: Because the database will synchronize the (write) access to the row (or even page in memory). One of the two **will** be the "first" and the other the "second". - that's the whole point of using a relational database that supports ACID.